# How to read and write into a ArrayList simmultaneousy

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads t1 and t2 accessing an `ArrayList`.

I want the threads to access it unless they are reading and writing on same index.

How can I do it without using any concurrent api and collections of java 5?

Comment: you mean "unless they are reading and writing on same index." (removed the not)?

Comment: can you use the concurrent collections of the more recent apis? or you cannot use any of the concurrent collection classes?

Comment: yes unless reading and writing on same index.I dont want to use any java5 api?

Comment: Bear in mind that removal of an index will shift all other indexes down, therefore affecting what the threads are doing!

Comment: See [Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: @Miquel I am not sure that that is really a concern. Unless an Object is being access by two threads simultaniously.

Comment: I know we can use synchronization and built in methods.How to do it without any built in methods

Comment: A full answer is given [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java.html).

Comment: the simple  ans will be see implementation of synchronized and concurrent api in java 5

Comment: @JohnKane hmm. but that's precisely his question, he's got t1 and t2 accessing the arraylist

Comment: @Miquel sorry, I said that wrong. What I meant was that you shouldn't have to worry so much about the index to an element, you need to be more concerned with the race conditions. Though, it kind of depends on your implementation I guess. Typically I try to avoid having multiple threads iterating through lists simultaniously. It seems like it is a better idea to have one thread that does that and feeds the others when ever possible. If not, then maybe a list isnt the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in a **correct** program you can't share a mutable object between multiple threads and not use any synchronization. It is hard to come up with some sort of a helpful answer without knowing what your application does. Maybe you could split up your `ArrayList` between threads so that each of them would work with its own version and then concatenate the results afterwards. Or, if you are implementing producer-consumer scenario, it is possible to do away with a couple of java monitors and a off the shelf implementation of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the two threads do not access to the same index at the same time there may be a problem if Array is reallocated, cf. 
ArrayList.ensureCapacity

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/package-info.java#package-info) is probably a really good place to start. Looking through how some of the issues were addressed will really help. [This book](http://books.google.com/books?id=-x1S4neCSOYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)  along with [looking through this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) will help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it help you - [Collections.synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) class.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the following: 
A. Change your data structure into a map of ArrayList (let's say - a map of 10 entries) in order to reduce locking time on the ArrayList (use the object's hashCode() % 10 in order to perform access to the proper ArrayList that is held in the map 
The ArrayList in each map entry will be Synchronized (u can get a Synchronized version of it using  Collections.synchronizedList 
B. Use ReaderWriterLock in order to give a better locking to your application. The disadvantage of using this that you have to go on any scneario that uses the ArrayList and understand if you need to lock for read or lock for write 
C. Combine A and B 
However, in many cases - the proper synchronization strategy relies on the use cases - do you expect to have more readers than writes ? If so, Use ReaderWriterLock, if not - Rw lock might not help you.

Comment: +1 for A.  I think that's the only real, useful solution to the problem.  (Though inserts could get interesting.)  I used something like it (for a TreeMap, though) when working in Java 1.4.